# Question on lambda expressions as parameters

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda

I'm a Java developer that is new to kotlin, and the following syntax surprised me:

```
    fun foo(m: String, bar: (m: String) -> Unit) {
        bar(m)
    }

    foo("test") {
        println("this is a $it")
    }
```

Here we see that the lambda expression is passed implicitly via a code block.

Is there a name for this type of syntactic trickery? I would like to understand this better.

Comment: Are you talking about how it is passed outside the parentheses, or just that it's passed at all? Being able to pass them around at all is simply what lambdas are.

Comment: The fact that it is outside the parenthesis

Comment: "Trailing lambda" https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter They make chained functional programming calls, scope functions (let, apply, also, etc), coroutine syntax, and type-safe builders all much cleaner in syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Tenfour04 - "Trailing lambda" is what I was looking for.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter